# Is it possible to connect EPSON ET 2815 to computer, not smartphone [Partly resolved]

Tags: printer

Partly resolved with the help of the video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pkoPnZgUD7o

Connect to printer via printer's own WiFi (WiFi Direct option) and then setup via Settings - works.

---

But the problem still exists - cannot connect to printer via the usual WiFi.

---

Bought new EPSON ET 2815. Connected it to smartphone - it can print.

But failed all attempts to connect the notebooks.
All the videos found on youtube - show how to connect to smartphone, but not to notebooks.
May be connection to notebooks - does not work at all  ?

Difficult to imagine that it might be so, but I am kind of desperate and so asking here - any advices what to do ?

Connection via Windows "Settings" - does not work - the printer can be detected by connection fails. Same story with native Epson application for Windows - cannot connect.

Windows can see printer :
[image]

But after "Add device" and waiting some time:
[image]

Comment: Hi Alexander, welcome to Hardware Recs! Unfortunately we really only handle questions about acquiring new hardware here, not debugging and troubleshooting existing hardware. You may get more help on Super User.